# Where is the apolloquery component from?

Tags: vue.js, vue-apollo

I'm trying to implement the vue-apollo package. Following the docs and all references I can find, data is fetched using the apolloquery component, either via template literals or a require.

I have tried:
The compiler fails when I try to import schema file using require or import.
I converted it into an exported constant and also used the raw gql

The problem:
Vue is unable to locate the apolloquery, so it doesn't know what to do with the query even when it's eventually able to parse the query

My code here https://github.com/nmeri17/aptiw-assessment/blob/6b96772a63bcb8a26a95bcd369dca4dc52cef6e0/resources/js/Pages/Tasks/Index.vue#L82C19-L82C19